# What is the inverse of `to_dense_batch` in Pytorch Geometric?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-geometric

`to_dense_batch`([doc](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/utils.html#torch_geometric.utils.to_dense_batch)) converts mini-batch to dense batch. How to convert the dense batch back to the mini-batch? Is there something like "from_dense_batch", which accept `dense_batch` and `mask`, and gives mini-batched `data`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a possible work around, but I not sure where it is the best implementation. The following is my code with test example.

```
from torch_geometric.datasets import TUDataset
from torch_geometric.loader import DataLoader
import torch
from torch_geometric.utils import to_dense_batch


def from_dense_batch(dense_bath, mask):
    # dense batch, B, N, F
    # mask, B, N
    B, N, F = dense_bath.size()
    flatten_dense_batch = dense_bath.view(-1, F)
    flatten_mask = mask.view(-1)
    data_x = flatten_dense_batch[flatten_mask, :]
    num_nodes = torch.sum(mask, dim=1)  # B, like 3,4,3
    pr_value = torch.cumsum(num_nodes, dim=0)  # B, like 3,7,10
    indicator_vector = torch.zeros(torch.sum(num_nodes, dim=0))
    indicator_vector[pr_value[:-1]] = 1  # num_of_nodes, 0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1
    data_batch = torch.cumsum(indicator_vector, dim=0)  # num_of_nodes, 0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2
    return data_x, data_batch


dataset = TUDataset(root='/tmp/ENZYMES', name='ENZYMES', use_node_attr=True)
loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)

test_batch = next(iter(loader))
dense_data, mask = to_dense_batch(test_batch.x, test_batch.batch)
output_data, output_batch = from_dense_batch(dense_data, mask)
print((test_batch.x == output_data).all())
print((test_batch.batch == output_batch).all())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy, please see this issue in PyG: [Inverse of 'dense to batch'](https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric/discussions/6948)

```
x, mask = to_dense_batch(x, batch)
x = x[mask]
```